# PHP - Copy File To Folder

Tags: php, file, path, copy

i have problem to copy same file name ex : 00000.php to the same folder (00000)
note : folder & file (.php) was create by "Hash" code.
it's my code :

```html
<?php
header ('Location: admin.php');

// Variables
$ads= $_POST['ads'];
$navbar = $_POST['navbar'];
$slider = $_POST['slidermenu'];
$news = $_POST['news'];
$items = $_POST['items'];
$footer = $_POST['footer'];
$rand = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . time());
// File Open
chdir("../pages/");
mkdir($rand);
$filename = fopen($cd . $rand . "." . "php" ,"a"); 
copy($filename,$rand);


// Should Include It's Head (Css / Js)
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/settings.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");


// Start Function For Radio Boxs
if ($ads == "ads-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/ads.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}

if ($navbar== "navbar-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/navbar.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}

if ($slider == "slidermenu-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/slider.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}

if ($news== "news-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/news.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}

if ($items == "items-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/items.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}

if ($footer== "footer-yes") {          
fwrite($filename,'<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/include/footer.php"); ?>');
fwrite($filename,"\n");    
}
// End Function For Radio Boxs


// File Close
fclose($handle);
exit;
?>
```

Images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkoT.png

thanks

Comment: what is $cd? use absolute path "../pages/"

Comment: Please debug your own code and provide an isolated and reproducable problem part, explain in detail what the specific problem is, what you have tried to solve it and why this didn't work for you

Comment: hi , it was work for me and it's fixed , but i tied to copy the .php file to folder !!

Comment: i want do this :  images [http://8pic.ir/images/taiae5n03cv85ipckuop.png ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **don't** try to copy a file which is currently opened by PHP before writing data to that file, are you?

Its like everything on the computer: You should first WRITE the file before trying to copy it.

ALSO you try to create a file in its folders location.

What are you copying:

```
/example.php to /example -> copy($filename,$rand);
```

What are you trying to copy:

```
/example.php to /example/example.php -> copy($filename,$rand."/".$filename);
```

Comment: this is inform to you : 1) i was create a file for create a .php , in this file after you click on "Create" , data send to my action file ( action.php ) 2) everything is right but , when i create a file & folder i tier to copy the File to the Folder !!